# Selenium parse data into a variable

Tags: python, variables, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible for Selenium to parse the source-code and locate specific text which is "Last updated" and then copy the whole line with date and time into a variable ?

HTML - code to be coped into a variable

```
Last updated: <strong>31.12.2015 17.46</strong>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the `strong` element that has this specific [preceding text sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[contains(preceding-sibling::text(), 'Last updated: ')]").text
```

Comment: That didn't work gave me this error: ' `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//strong[preceding-sibling::text() = 'Last updated: ']"}`

Comment: @user3580316 could be several reasons for that - can you provide the URL of the page you are working with so I can reproduce the problem too? Thanks.

Comment: Since this is a page you enter after authentication, I am not able to do so. However I can provide you with the source code which may be to help ? Just look for "Last updated" and you will find the string. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1sbhtgnjh4yg4do/source-code.txt